# What are the 132 types of upachaara?

Tags: puja

एकोद्वात्रिंशोपचार they are called. There are many types of upachaara pujas. Minimum is panchopchaar 5 upchaar one.. & maximum I got to know is 132. Raajopchaar is 64 upchaar & only till there's information is available on internet. Please tell about what are those 132 upchaaras.

Comment: I also know about the names of only the 64 upacharas 

Comment: Where is written that एकोद्वात्रिंश means 132? The word itself seems incorrect!

Comment: @Rickross I also think 64 is the maximum given in the Vrihat-Tantrasara.

Comment: Here on Wikipedia - https://hi.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/पूजा

Comment: That link is not working!

Comment: Wait I add screenshot

Comment: How to upload screenshot here?